# Is my cabin class based on my operating airline or my marketing airline?

Tags: airlines, bookings, fare-class, fare-basis

I just got an XML for my PNR from Sabre which held two components:

- ResBookDesigCode="X"
- MarketingCabin="Y"
- MarketingAirline Code="DL"/>
- OperatingAirline Code="WA" CompanyShortName="KLM CITYHOPPER"/>

How can I figure out what fare am I suppose to use to determine the real cabin the PNR is on (economy, premium etc.)?

I am using a combination of airline+fare, but I'm not sure which one I'm suppose to use.

Should I use the marketing or Res/operated airline?

Comment: Did you book the ticket already? If so, what does the rest of the issued ticket say?

Comment: Yes, its already ticketed. I'm not sure how to find the cabin class.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the ticket (hiding your name and the PNR)?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan!
not all of it since there are some private info of the traveler, but there you go... I hope it helps!

Comment: RPH="3" ResBookDesigCode="X" SmokingAllowed="false" StopQuantity="0" eTicket="false">
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="AMS"/>
    <Equipment AirEquipType="F70"/>
    <FlightDetails TrafficRestrictionCode="G">
     <Text>OPERATED BY KLM CITYHOPPER</Text>
    </FlightDetails>
    <MarketingAirline Code="DL" FlightNumber="9293"/>
    <MarriageGrp Ind="O"/>
    <OperatingAirline Code="WA" CompanyShortName="KLM CITYHOPPER"/>

Comment: <OriginLocation LocationCode="HAJ"/>
   </FlightSegment>
   <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="03-03T12:37" ConnectionInd="I" DepartureDateTime="03-03T10:30" DestinationTimeZone="-5" ElapsedTime="08.07" FlightNumber="125" MarketingCabin="Y" OriginTimeZone="1"

Comment: KLM Cityhopper only handles short-haul European flights where all seats are basically the same. Therefore what 'cabin' you're in  is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @pnuts JonathanReez Is obliquely suggesting that Euro business is no different to Euro Y, because the seats are the same. As someone who likes some space around me (blocked middle seat) and hot food after a long day, I would disagree, but that's why there's a choice. Also the points or miles accumulated may differ quite sharply.

Comment: @pnuts OP's flight is from Hanover to Amsterdam, which takes around 60 minutes

Comment: @Calchas Since Delta is the marketing career, OP seems to be flying in from the US with them. Whatever miles are accumulated would be mostly based on his long-haul leg.

Comment: @JonathanReez True, but in some programmes (e.g., Flying Blue) you need a certain number of qualifying flights, so the length of the flight is not important for status, only whether it qualifies. I remember when DL brought in their X bucket a few years ago, at first KLM did not recognize it as a qualifying bucket and I had to take an extra flight just before the New Year to maintain my platinum status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the marketing cabin is Y, then you're in economy.

You can also use the fact that Delta's "X" fare class is an economy class. It is unlikely to map to a business seat on another carrier.

Comment: So basically you are saying that the marketing airline is the one who I should be following (Y)... and not the operating one (X)

Comment: @IshaiAnkri The booking code (X) and the cabin (Y) are different things.

Answer (score 4):

The 'cabin' codes are fairly well standardized:

- Y - Economy
- W - Premium Economy
- J/C - Business
- F - First

But there are variations and special cases*.  Though 100%, your Y cabin is economy.

Note, this is different from the fare code X which books into Y, as would M, N, Q etc.

*For example Etihad's The Residence.  I do not know what code they use.

Comment: EY uses F for the Residence. The only other cabin code I know was "R", which was used by British Airways on their one-class supersonic services.